# How to getting text labels to show up in scatter chart

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I want **text labels** for my scatter plot that is connected with points in the graph.

my data is like this.

| Text labels | Ham | spam |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dec-20 | 20 | 0.5 |
| Jan+21 | 1 | 3 |
| Feb-21 | 0.5 | 15 |
| Mar+21 | 0.9 | 4 |
| Apr_21 | 0.1 | 1 |

The chart removes the labels and places numbers. How do I get the text labels back?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line graphs are better suited to your needs, not scatter plot.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This one really was stumping me.